Jackstand position on control arms
Is this a safe position for a jackstand, right where (something that resembles) the frame meets the drivetrain? It's a Mazda 3 2013. I had to put it there because the jack (seen in the back) took the only other obviously secure spot to absorb it.


From the angle of the image, it looks to be fine. You could also put it under the A-arm itself without worry, as long as you put it in a spot where the stand won't slip or slide. There is a hole in the center of the A-arm where this would work out just fine.
